# How to change primary group

Tags: user-management

I want to remove user `pserver` from the group `apache`.

```
#deluser pserver apache
/usr/sbin/deluser: You may not remove the user from their primary group.
```

Now I want to add a new primary group, so I ran the following;

```
#usermod -G pserver pserver
```

Which returned the following:

```
pserver` is now in group `pserver

#groups pserver
pserver : apache pserver
```

Now I want to remove the user again from group apache, but I get same error again. How can I delete `pserver` from the primary group `apache`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `usermod` option `-G` adds supplementary groups. You want option `-g` to change the primary group. I.e. your command should have been:

```
# usermod -g pserver pserver
```

Note, this will also change group ownership of files in the home directory, but not elsewhere.

More generally, the syntax for changing user 'user' to have primary group 'group' is:

```
# usermod -g group user
```

Comment: Not clear in this command which is the user and which is the group, since in this unique circumstance they're both identical, but it frequently won't be that way.

Comment: Text updated to answer the above comment

Comment: To see the immediate change of the user groups issue following commands:
`su - ${USER}` and then `id -nG`

Answer (score 7):

Late, but a bit clear (at least for me);

```
sudo usermod -g <NewPrimaryGroupName> <TheTargetUserName>
```

And then check `id`

```
id <TheTargetUserName>
```

More details here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/usermod.8.html

Credits: http://www.htpcbeginner.com/safely-change-primary-group-group-in-linux/

Thank for reply.

Answer (score 2):

*The question as placed by the OP is misleading.* The title reads "How to **change** primary group", however in the question body its clear the intent is to not just replace the primary group but also **remove** the previous primary.

In case anyone wants to just **replace** the primary but not remove it from the list, one simply has to add the previous primary back to list.

So, after following [StarNamer](https://askubuntu.com/users/77740/starnamer)'s [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/165946/665626), one only needs to do a

```
adduser user previous-primary-group
```

because the usermod command will have thrown out your previous primary group from the list of groups you belong to.