# How to create file as specific group

Tags: groups

This may sound odd.

My username is ubuntu and my machine is called ubuntu.

What I want is when I create a file in some folder that it has a signature

```
user      group
ubuntu    www-data
```

at the moment whatever i create has a signature

```
ubuntu    ubuntu
```

Can I simply remove my user from group ubuntu and add it to group www-data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sudo chgrp www-data *yourfile*` will do it for individual files.

to do it for all files within a specific directory, change the group for that directory with the same command

`sudo chgrp www-data /path/to/your/dir`

then use the `chmod` command to make all files created within that directory belong to the group the directory belongs to with

`sudo chmod g+s /path/to/your/dir`

Comment: i don't want to change the group of the file. i want that file to have www-data group at the moment of creation

Comment: @lewis4u I had already added an option to do that. Refresh the page to see the edit.

Comment: Tanks @Will , you answer is really usefull to me, a few months in seach for this.

Answer (score 7):

The command `sg` can execute a command under a different group ID. If you are a member of the group `newgroup`, this should create `newfile` within that group :

```
sg newgroup "touch newfile"
```

(Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/how-to-apply-changes-of-newly-added-user-groups-without-needing-to-reboot)

Answer (score 2):

We can create a simple function, based on [`touch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/touch.1.html) and [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/chown.1.html) commands, which will create new empty files and will change their permissions simultaneously. Or when the file exists it just will change its permissions. For this purpose type in the terminal:

```
function touch-www { touch $1; chown $USER:www-data $1; }
export -f touch-www
```

Now we have a new command, called `touch-www`, and we can use it in this way:

```
touch-www /path/to/file
```

To be possible to use this new command everywhere in the file system let's modify the function in this way:

```
function touch-www { sudo touch $1; sudo chown $USER:www-data $1; }
export -f touch-www
```

Once the file have enough permissions we can edit it with the current user. So let's assume we want to use and [`nano`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nano.1.html) in the way described here. Let's create new function:

```
function nano-www { sudo touch $1; sudo chown $USER:www-data $1; nano $1; }
export -f nano-www
```

To be these new commands permanently available we can add these lines in the bottom of the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
function touch-www { sudo touch $1; sudo chown $USER:www-data $1; }
export -f touch-www

function nano-www { sudo touch $1; sudo chown $USER:www-data $1; nano $1; }
export -f nano-www
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you didn't read the question carefully. I don't want to change the group of the files. The keyword is "create" and not "change" what you are proposing is changing the files group after they are created.

Comment: @lewis4u Yes, you are right, I've got this idea and just decided to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to change the group and retain the user value, try

> sudo chown newuser:newgroup sample.txt

or in your case:

> sudo chown ubuntu:www-data sample.txt

Then run

> sudo chmod g+w sample.txt

Comment: sorry maybe i wasn't clear enough...i want the NEW files that i create to have already the www-data group!

Comment: My apologies. I did find [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/165946/676362), but it only pertains to files within your home directory

Answer (score 0):

You could create a www-data user, with www-data group as their primary [see `useradd`, `adduser`, or eg `kuser`], change to that user [`su www-data`] and then all files made would be owned by that user:group.

Backup `/etc/group` (or the whole of /etc) first before messing with groups. Also lookup what to do if you're [locked out because of group permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user).

Or, you could alter the primary group of the user named "ubuntu" to be www-data:

`sudo usermod --gid www-data ubuntu`.

*There may be security issues with the later as it might at some point (eg combined with other bugs) expose all files owned by that group to your web server. The point of www-data group is that only those files owned by it are allowed to be sent externally by the server (apache, nginx, whatever). Having all your standard user login files belong to that group thus creates a risk.*