# How to Allow two users to access one directory. (tried groups but failed)

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, users, groups

I want to allow access to 2 users on one directory. I am trying since days but unable to do so! Let me make it simple for you guys to understand by giving a simple example. But first, Let me tell you that the user named `admin` should be able to access both the directories.
Consider two Directories:

1. `/var/www/directory1`
2. `/var/www/directory2`

and two users:

1. `user1`
2. `user2`

I want `user1` to access only the directory `directory1`, `user2` to access the directory `directory2` and `admin` to access both the directories!

I tried giving ownership to respective directories to the users and the group named `admin-group` to let `admin` access both the directories. That didn't work well. I also tried giving write access to the group but failed.

Is it possible to do what I want? If possible, How can I?

Comment: If admin can use `sudo` to run as root, you don't need to grant it any special access rights, as they could just take them themselves when needed. However, your approach you described sounds about right if you don't want to rely on `sudo` powers. What exactly failed? Did you forget to make `admin` user a member of `admin-group`? What file system are those directories on? Note that the standard Linux permissions only work on file systems like ext4, but not on FAT or NTFS.

Comment: No! actually `admin` user has power to work on automation like updating software. `sudo` is not used and don't want to use as it's unstable for automation.

Comment: Well /var/www is sort of a potentially unique case. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www

Comment: For shared directories personally I like ACL see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setup-shared-directory/ and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Comment: What I am thinking to do is to make group for both the directory and add user to specific group. For example, `dir1group` with `dir1user1` and `dir2` with `dir2user1` and make `admin:dir1` owner of the group! But I don't think it's the standard way. But by doing this I will be able to allow more users to access the directory too!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
chown user1:admin-group /var/www/directory1
chown user2:admin-group /var/www/directory2
chmod 770 /var/www/directory1
chmod 770 /var/www/directory2
usermod -aG admin-group admin
```

Then you have to make sure that new files created in the directories use the [same permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/903750/566421):

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/directory1
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/directory2
```

Comment: I can't understand why permissions should be changed to `770`. It's not at all good. Others may want execute rights!

Comment: @AdarshSojitra - See the link I gave you for security concerns.https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www . Also x permissions on directories are not the same as on files see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions .

Comment: @AdarshSojitra Sorry, I was assuming you didn't want user1 to have any access to user2's directory and visa-versa.

Comment: I am trying! hope it will work!

Comment: @AdarshSojitra the answer has been updated.